# Zend forms to display information from a database

Tags: php, zend-form

I would like to create a form using Zend forms and display information in it, which is stored in my database. The amount of rows required varies depending on the user.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? My only knowledge with zend forms is creating a form for a pre-determined number of fields.

I am using Zend 1.12
I have looked round Google but not been able to find anything that would suggest that it is possible. My knowledge of Zend is not that good. I am currently displaying the database information by using a partial loop in my view and adding html to that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.quickstart.html.

It's no problem to dynamically add elements to the form:

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
foreach ($userFields as $fieldName) {
    $form->addElement('text', $fieldName);
}
```